# JS Video Player from video download link

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible play video from remote download video link.
For example I have link http://vidrack-media.s3.amazonaws.com/student_47e96b83-989e-437a-8953-0d068308e25f.mp4
I wanna render any video player where I can watch this video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in nearly every player.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://vidrack-media.s3.amazonaws.com/student_47e96b83-989e-437a-8953-0d068308e25f.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```